# IIS Website Creation - AIZ file format question

Tags: iis

I am working with a system which automatically creates entries for websites in IIS 6.0.  It seems to do this by creating a list of ".aiz" files for each site.  I've tried searching the intertubes, but I can't find any documentation on where these files come from or why they should be used.  Does anyone have any documentation they can point me to regarding this file format and IIS 6.0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find anything either and have never seen them specifically for use with IIS.  My assumption would be that the system you're using them generates them and runs some kind of automation process against them, scripts or something proprietary.  Are you able to read them or are they binary?  What's the system that you're using?  Maybe they have some information on their support site.

Comment: Unfortunately I am the support now :( and the wonderful folks I inherited this from think documentation is a city in China.  I can read the scripts - they look like they were simple IIS host headers - creating one manual doesn't do anything so I am thinking that you are correct regarding the automation process - I just can't find it. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, that's a drag...  Glad to help.  Good luck!